# Proving $x \lt y \iff x^n \lt y^n $

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Let F be an ordered field.

$ x,y \in F, x,y \ge 0 $ and $n \in N$

Prove that:

$$ x \lt y \iff x^n \lt y^n$$

Now I'm choosing to use induction to prove this (is that the only way to prove this?)
and have:

For n=1

$x^1 \lt y^1 \Rightarrow x \lt y$

The assumption that for $n=k$ where $k \in N$ is true, then for  $n=k+1$:

$$x^kx \lt y^ky $$

Now after this step I'm quite confused as to what to write next. Is it enough to leave it at the last step or is there more in order for the proof to be concrete?

Comment: "Then for $n=k+1$..." you have $x^{k+1}=x^kx<y^k x < y^k y<\dots$, taking a moment to explain why each equality or inequality in the chain holds if it is not completely obvious (e.g. where you use your induction hypothesis or other hypotheses).  Do not begin with $x^{k+1}<y^{k+1}$ as this is what you want to prove.  Begin at one side and through a series of conclusions arrive at the other side at the very end.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews fixed it thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$x^{n+1} = x^n.x \lt x^n.y < y^n.y = y^{n+1}$

Note that $x^n$ should be positive.

Answer (score 1):

you can proceed by using the factorization of $$(y^n)-(x^n)=(y-x)((y^n-1)+(y^n-2)(x)+....+(x^n-1))$$   as the later part is always positive you get directly the answer.

here, $x,y$ should be satisfying all the constraints given.